# GeForce 8600M GT Drivers

Tags: kernel, gpu-driver

I am trying to get Ubuntu running smoothly on my old laptop using an NVIDIA GeForce 8600M GT, but several applications will frequently freeze up. I’m fairly confident that this is an issue with the driver for my GPU (nouveau). My attempts to try the NVIDIA 340.108 driver led me down a rabbit hole of misery and ultimately I nuked the disk and performed a fresh install of Ubuntu. From what I’ve read, it looks like I may need to install an old kernel (maybe 5.4 or 5.7?) since driver support has been dropped for these old GPUs on newer kernels. If that is true, could anyone offer guidance on how to install an old kernel and whether to try and stick with nouveau drivers or switch to the NVIDIA 340.108 driver for use with the old kernel? My previous experience in trying to do this led to an libssl dependency for the old kernel that I couldn’t resolve because of complaints about trying to grab unsigned files. This was after modifying the apt/sources.list with deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main. Anyways, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated on how I can get my GPU drivers to work properly.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6 22.04 LTS

Comment: Eventually got the 5.4.205 kernel installed and the tried installing the NVIDIA driver but now the bootup ends in a black screen with nothing on it after briefly displaying the Ubutunu loading screen. I can still access tty2 and go through the nvidia 304.108 driver installation, but I’m still stuck at the black screen and do not know how to progress.

Comment: Installing the 5.4 kernel to Ubuntu 22.04 is a bad idea. Why not use 20.04 with `linux-generic`? You will need to install 20.04 with no point.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did a fresh install of 20.04, but when trying to install the NVIDIA drivers through the Ubuntu software drivers, I also get an unsuccessful install and only get a black screen when booting. I may try to install the 5.4.0 kernel and retry with Ubuntu 20.04. Previously, I had tried Ubtuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.4.205. Maybe I needed to use 5.4.0 instead of 5.4.205 for the NVIDIA driver. Is there a better way to determine kernel compatibility with the NVIDIA driver than trawling through random old suggestions on the web? I’m still assuming the kernel is the issue. Not confident about that

Comment: You can check kernel compatibility of Nvidia drivers at their site. But I think the 340 drivers from Ubuntu repositories should work on 20.04 with the 5.4 Ubuntu kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I installed lubuntu to dell inspiron 1720 laptop which had the intel video chipset.  Then I moved the hard drive to another inspiron 1720 that had the Nvidia 8600M graphics card.  It worked.

I tried and tried before to install lubuntu directly to the Dell Inspiron 1720 with the Nvidia 8600M graphics and it didn't work.  It was like being in a small hell considering I have probably 25 of these laptops.

Try to install your linux to a box other than the box with the Nvidia 8600M and then move the hard drive after installation.  For some reason that worked for me :)

Good luck.